# Are all pronouns proforms?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, pro-forms

The definition of a [pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pronoun) according to the *Merriam-Webster Dictionary* is "any of a small set of words... that are used as substitutes for nouns or noun phrases". The definition of a pro-form according to *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics* is a "term used... to
refer collectively to the items in a sentence which substitute for other items or
constructions," fully captured below:

[image: pro-form definition]

Additionally, here is the same dictionary's entry for pronoun:

[image: pronoun definition]

The Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) for pronoun has the following diagram distinguishing pro-forms from pronouns:

[image: pro-form vs pronoun table]

The justifications for (3) and (4) are that "in (3), the interrogative pronoun does not stand in for anything. Similarly, in (4), it is a dummy pronoun, one that does not stand in for anything."

I am having troubling squaring how we distinguish pronouns from pro-forms with how we define pronouns and pro-forms. Am I correct in attempting to clarify that pronouns are *not* simply 'words used as substitutes for nouns' (which would make pronouns a subset of pro-forms), but instead, pronouns can **embody additional grammatical content** (i.e, the interrogative and dummy pronoun forms seen in (3) & (4)) that no noun could represent (i.e, there exists pronouns that aren't substitutions for nouns, thus non-pro-form pronouns)? Or am I babbling nonsensically, and I am missing some basic logic?

Comment: I would rather say that pronouns are a class of words that inherently, lexically, _can_ stand in for other items, whereas pro-form are elements in concrete sentences/contexts that _do_ stand in for other items. There’s a great deal of overlap between the two, but neither is a subset of the other (cf. 5 and 6 in the table, which are both pro-forms, but not pronouns). A pronoun is a pronoun even without a sentence; a pro-form can only exist in a specific context – it’s not a class of word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thank you. i have noticed in many definitions of pronoun the subtle use of 'can' or 'may', which seems to indicate exactly what you are saying.

Comment: As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form), there are lots of other types of pro-forms than just pronouns: pro-verbs, pro-adjectives, and so on. (There are probably pro-forms for all types of speech.) But that other Wikipedia article is a little confusing, as it suggests *it* isn't a pro-form, but I think it still is one, it's just that in some uses it has no anaphora. [Dummy pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) can be analysed in many ways, but I don't think it would be a helpful way to say they stop being pro-forms.

Comment: @curiousdannii in that case, you disagree with the 'Pronouns vs pro-forms' table from the pronoun wiki?

Comment: @shea Yes, from my understanding of pro-forms, the pronoun page is either badly written or just straight wrong. But I could be wrong...

Comment: Consider: A: "Was she arrested?", B: "I'm afraid so". Here, "so" is a pro-form (interpreted anaphorically as "she was arrested", but it isn't a pronoun because "afraid" doesn't take any kind of NP.

Comment: @BillJ thanks, i think i understand theoretically the distinction between pro-forms and pronouns. my question pertains to the validity of the definition of 'pronoun' seen in various dictionaries, as answered in the negative above by other users.